# Determine how many bits are in a floating point value

Tags: c, homework, floating-point

I'm writing a program which determines how many bits are in a floating point value (this will be run on Unix).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void countbits(int k);

int main(){
    int input;
    // int a = (int) malloc(sizeof(int));
    printf("Please enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d",&input);
    // a = input;

    countbits(input);
}

void countbits(int k){
    int j,count;
    count = 0;
    for(j = 0; j < 31; j++){
        if(k & 0x000001 == 1){
        count++;
        }
        k >>= 1;
    }
    printf("%d has %d bits set\n",k,count);
    // count = 0;
}
```

Output example:

> 2 has 1 bits set
>   6 has 2 bits set
>   32 has 1 bits set

I'll really appreciate any feedback or correction or if there is something I can do better.

Comment: I don't see how this code has anything to do with [tag:floating-point]. Please explain? I'm putting the question back on hold in the meantime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do the output in `main()`, not in `countbits()`.  Functions should have only one primary purpose, according to the [Single Responsibility Principle (SRP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).  In this case, `countbits()` should just perform the calculations and return the result.  Thus, its return type should now be of type `int`.

Inside of `countbits()`, you could just loop while `k` is not `0` instead of looping 32 times.  Once all the bits in `k` shift away and `k` becomes `0`, there's no point in continuing.  This will also give you a result of `0` right away if the input is `0`; calculating this will be a waste of time.

```
int main(void) {
    int input;

    // get the input...

    int count = countbits(input);

    printf("%d has %d bits set\n", input, count);
}

int countbits(int k) {
    int count = 0;

    while (k != 0) {
        // perform calculations...
    }

    return count;
}
```

Some notes about this and other things:

- `main()` should have a `void` parameter since it isn't taking any command line arguments.
- The first (unformatted) output in `main()` should use [`puts()` instead of `printf()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454474/what-is-the-difference-between-printf-and-puts-in-c).
- `count` doesn't need to be declared and then assigned to `0`.  Just initialize it to `0`.
- `j` should be initialized inside the `for` loop statement (if you have C99).  If you don't, then declare it *right* before the loop.  Variables should be used as close in scope as possible.

Comment: Thanks Jamal! Can you talk little bit about my method in countbits. I'm not so sure about it if its correct.

Comment: Professor gave us example what our program should output he has 4 prints 2. 32 prints 2. 16 prints 3. 2 prints 1. However my 32, 4, 16, 2 all prints 1.

Comment: @user3478869: Since this isn't working as it should, I will have to place the question on hold until it works.  We only review working code (and I had assumed it was tested for correctness first).  You can ask Stack Overflow on how to fix this.  After it works, edit in the changes (but do *not* apply my changes), and the hold can be removed.

Comment: It has been confirmed that it is working correctly.

Comment: @user3478869: With the current code, or with some changes?  My test code is also showing different results from the expected output.

Comment: I figured that his expected output is wrong. He just have a dummy example to give an idea what program should output.

Comment: @user3478869: If so, then update the question with the expected output, if you're sure (worked it out and everything).

Comment: Wait, scratch that.  Your current output is correct, which is what I'm getting as well.  I'm not sure why your professor has given you those values.